# Сортировка по цене по умолчанию на Битрикс

Tags: сортировка, битрикс

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как сделать чтобы по умолчанию сортировалось по цене в Битрикс. Сейчас сортирует по всякому, но не по цене. Не ставится она по-умолчанию почему-то.

Сортировка в каталоге товаров. Показ ТОП отключен. Для сортировки используется компонент `Alfa Systems: сортировка каталога`. Ниже привожу код файла `/bitrix/templates/тема/components/bitrix/catalog/тема/section.php` "без купюр":

```html
<?if(!defined('B_PROLOG_INCLUDED') || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
?><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="catalog"><?
    ?><tr><?
        ?><td valign="top" width="240"><?
        if($arResult['HAVE_CHILDREN']=='Y'){
            if($arParams['USE_FILTER']=='Y'){
                $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                    'bitrix:catalog.smart.filter',
                    'empty',
                    Array(
                        'IBLOCK_TYPE' => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
                        'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
                        'SECTION_ID' => $arResult['SECTION_ID'],
                        'FILTER_NAME' => $arParams['FILTER_NAME'],
                        'PRICE_CODE' => $arParams['FILTER_PRICE_CODE'],
                        'CACHE_TYPE' => $arParams['CACHE_TYPE'],
                        'CACHE_TIME' => $arParams['CACHE_TIME'],
                        'CACHE_NOTES' => '',
                        'CACHE_GROUPS' => $arParams['CACHE_GROUPS'],
                        'SAVE_IN_SESSION' => 'N',
                        'XML_EXPORT' => 'Y',
                        'SECTION_TITLE' => 'NAME',
                        'SECTION_DESCRIPTION' => 'DESCRIPTION'
                    ),
                    $component
                );
            }
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                'bitrix:catalog.section.list',
                's_in_s',
                Array(
                    'IBLOCK_TYPE' => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
                    'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
                    'SECTION_ID' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_ID'],
                    'SECTION_CODE' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_CODE'],
                    'CACHE_TYPE' => $arParams['CACHE_TYPE'],
                    'CACHE_TIME' => $arParams['CACHE_TIME'],
                    'CACHE_GROUPS' => $arParams['CACHE_GROUPS'],
                    'COUNT_ELEMENTS' => $arParams['SECTION_COUNT_ELEMENTS'],
                    'TOP_DEPTH' => $arParams['SECTION_TOP_DEPTH'],
                    'SECTION_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['section'],
                    'ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN' => 'N',
                    'FILTER_URI_ADD' => $arResult['FILTER_URI_ADD']
                ),
                $component
            );
        }
        elseif($arParams['USE_FILTER']=='Y'){
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                'bitrix:catalog.smart.filter',
                'electro',
                Array(
                    'IBLOCK_TYPE' => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
                    'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
                    'SECTION_ID' => $arResult['SECTION_ID'],
                    'FILTER_NAME' => $arParams['FILTER_NAME'],
                    'PRICE_CODE' => $arParams['FILTER_PRICE_CODE'],
                    'CACHE_TYPE' => $arParams['CACHE_TYPE'],
                    'CACHE_TIME' => $arParams['CACHE_TIME'],
                    'CACHE_NOTES' => '',
                    'CACHE_GROUPS' => $arParams['CACHE_GROUPS'],
                    'SAVE_IN_SESSION' => 'N',
                    'XML_EXPORT' => 'Y',
                    'SECTION_TITLE' => 'NAME',
                    'SECTION_DESCRIPTION' => 'DESCRIPTION'
                ),
                $component
            );
        }
        ?></td><td valign="top"><?
        if($arResult['HAVE_CHILDREN']=='Y'){
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                'bitrix:catalog.section.list',
                's_in_c',
                Array(
                    'IBLOCK_TYPE' => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
                    'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
                    'SECTION_ID' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_ID'],
                    'SECTION_CODE' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_CODE'],
                    'LIST_PROPERTY_CODE' => $arParams['LIST_PROPERTY_CODE'],
                    'CACHE_TYPE' => $arParams['CACHE_TYPE'],
                    'CACHE_TIME' => $arParams['CACHE_TIME'],
                    'CACHE_GROUPS' => $arParams['CACHE_GROUPS'],
                    'COUNT_ELEMENTS' => $arParams['SECTION_COUNT_ELEMENTS'],
                    'TOP_DEPTH' => $arParams['SECTION_TOP_DEPTH'],
                    'SECTION_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['section'],
                    'PRICE_CODE' => $arParams['PRICE_CODE'],
                    'FILTER_NAME' => $arParams['FILTER_NAME'],
                    'CONVERT_CURRENCY' => $arParams['CONVERT_CURRENCY'],
                    'CURRENCY_ID' => $arParams['CURRENCY_ID'],
                    'USE_COMPARE' => $arParams['USE_COMPARE'],
                    'OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES' => $arParams['OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES'],
                    'OFFERS_FIELD_CODE' => $arParams['LIST_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE'],
                    'OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE' => $arParams['LIST_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE'],
                    'OFFERS_SORT_FIELD' => $arParams['OFFERS_SORT_FIELD'],
                    'OFFERS_SORT_ORDER' => $arParams['OFFERS_SORT_ORDER'],
                    'OFFERS_LIMIT' => $arParams['LIST_OFFERS_LIMIT'],
                    'FILTER_URI_ADD' => $arResult['FILTER_URI_ADD'],
                    'MAX_WIDTH' => $arParams['LIST_MAX_WIDTH'],
                    'MAX_HEIGHT' => $arParams['LIST_MAX_HEIGHT'],
                    'LIST_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT' => $arParams['LIST_PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT'],
                ),
                $component
            );

            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                'bitrix:catalog.section',
                'empty',
                array(
                    'IBLOCK_TYPE' => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
                    'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
                    'META_KEYWORDS' => $arParams['LIST_META_KEYWORDS'],
                    'META_DESCRIPTION' => $arParams['LIST_META_DESCRIPTION'],
                    'BROWSER_TITLE' => $arParams['LIST_BROWSER_TITLE'],
                    'SET_TITLE' => $arParams['SET_TITLE'],
                    'SECTION_ID' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_ID'],
                    'SECTION_CODE' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_CODE'],
                    'SECTION_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['section'],
                    'DETAIL_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['element'],
                    'COMPARE_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['compare'],
                ),
                $component
            );
        }
        else{
            ?><div class="sec_with_elem"><?
                ?><h1 class="pagetitle_catalog"><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false)?></h1><?
                if($arResult['SECTION_DATA']['DESCRIPTION']!=''):
                    ?><p><?=$arResult['SECTION_DATA']['DESCRIPTION']?></p><?
                endif;
                ?><div class="hr"></div><?
                global $alfaCTemplate, $alfaCSortType, $alfaCSortToo, $alfaCOutput;
                $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                    'redsign:catalog.sorter',
                    'catalog',
                    Array(
                        'ALFA_ACTION_PARAM_NAME' => 'alfaction',
                        'ALFA_ACTION_PARAM_VALUE' => 'alfavalue',
                        'ALFA_CHOSE_TEMPLATES_SHOW' => 'Y',
                        'ALFA_CNT_TEMPLATES' => '2',
                        'ALFA_CNT_TEMPLATES_0' => 'tmple1',
                        'ALFA_CNT_TEMPLATES_NAME_0' => 'cat_l',
                        'ALFA_CNT_TEMPLATES_1' => 'tmple2',
                        'ALFA_CNT_TEMPLATES_NAME_1' => 'cat_b',
                        'ALFA_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE' => $arParams['ALFA_DEFAULT_TEMPLATE'],
                        'ALFA_SORT_BY_SHOW' => $arParams['ALFA_SORT_BY_SHOW'],
                        "ALFA_SORT_BY_NAME" => array(0=>"sort",1=>"name",2=>"catalog_price_1",),
                  "ALFA_SORT_BY_DEFAULT" => "catalog_price_1_asc",
                        'ALFA_OUTPUT_OF_SHOW' => $arParams['ALFA_OUTPUT_OF_SHOW'],
                        'ALFA_OUTPUT_OF' => $arParams['ALFA_OUTPUT_OF'],
                        'ALFA_OUTPUT_OF_DEFAULT' => $arParams['ALFA_OUTPUT_OF_DEFAULT'],
                        'ALFA_OUTPUT_OF_SHOW_ALL' => $arParams['ALFA_OUTPUT_OF_SHOW_ALL'],
                    ),
                    $component
                );

                $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                    'bitrix:catalog.section',
                    $alfaCTemplate,
                    array(
                        'IBLOCK_TYPE' => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
                        'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
                        'ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD' => $alfaCSortType, //$arParams['ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD'],
                        'ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER' => $alfaCSortToo, //$arParams['ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER'],
                        'PROPERTY_CODE' => $arParams['LIST_PROPERTY_CODE'],
                        'META_KEYWORDS' => $arParams['LIST_META_KEYWORDS'],
                        'META_DESCRIPTION' => $arParams['LIST_META_DESCRIPTION'],
                        'BROWSER_TITLE' => $arParams['LIST_BROWSER_TITLE'],
                        'INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS' => $arParams['INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS'],
                        'BASKET_URL' => $arParams['BASKET_URL'],
                        'ACTION_VARIABLE' => $arParams['ACTION_VARIABLE'],
                        'PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE' => $arParams['PRODUCT_ID_VARIABLE'],
                        'SECTION_ID_VARIABLE' => $arParams['SECTION_ID_VARIABLE'],
                        'PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE' => $arParams['PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE'],
                        'FILTER_NAME' => $arParams['FILTER_NAME'],
                        'CACHE_TYPE' => $arParams['CACHE_TYPE'],
                        'CACHE_TIME' => $arParams['CACHE_TIME'],
                        'CACHE_FILTER' => $arParams['CACHE_FILTER'],
                        'CACHE_GROUPS' => $arParams['CACHE_GROUPS'],
                        'SET_TITLE' => $arParams['SET_TITLE'],
                        'SET_STATUS_404' => $arParams['SET_STATUS_404'],
                        'DISPLAY_COMPARE' => $arParams['USE_COMPARE'],
                        'PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT' => $alfaCOutput,//$arParams['PAGE_ELEMENT_COUNT']
                        'LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT' => $alfaCOutput,//$arParams['LINE_ELEMENT_COUNT']
                        'PRICE_CODE' => $arParams['PRICE_CODE'],
                        'USE_PRICE_COUNT' => $arParams['USE_PRICE_COUNT'],
                        'SHOW_PRICE_COUNT' => $arParams['SHOW_PRICE_COUNT'],
                        'PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE' => $arParams['PRICE_VAT_INCLUDE'],
                        'USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY' => $arParams['USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY'],
                        'DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER' => $arParams['DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER'],
                        'DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER' => $arParams['DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER'],
                        'PAGER_TITLE' => $arParams['PAGER_TITLE'],
                        'PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS' => $arParams['PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS'],
                        'PAGER_TEMPLATE' => $arParams['PAGER_TEMPLATE'],
                        'PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING' => $arParams['PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING'],
                        'PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME' => $arParams['PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME'],
                        'PAGER_SHOW_ALL' => $arParams['PAGER_SHOW_ALL'],
                        'OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES' => $arParams['OFFERS_CART_PROPERTIES'],
                        'OFFERS_FIELD_CODE' => $arParams['LIST_OFFERS_FIELD_CODE'],
                        'OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE' => $arParams['LIST_OFFERS_PROPERTY_CODE'],
                        'OFFERS_SORT_FIELD' => $arParams['OFFERS_SORT_FIELD'],
                        'OFFERS_SORT_ORDER' => $arParams['OFFERS_SORT_ORDER'],
                        'OFFERS_LIMIT' => $arParams['LIST_OFFERS_LIMIT'],
                        'SECTION_ID' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_ID'],
                        'SECTION_CODE' => $arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_CODE'],
                        'SECTION_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['section'],
                        'DETAIL_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['element'],
                        'CONVERT_CURRENCY' => $arParams['CONVERT_CURRENCY'],
                        'CURRENCY_ID' => $arParams['CURRENCY_ID'],
                        'COMPARE_URL' => $arResult['FOLDER'].$arResult['URL_TEMPLATES']['compare'],
                        'COMPARE_NAME' => $arParams['COMPARE_NAME'],
                        'ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN' => 'Y',
                        'DISPLAY_TITLE' => 'N',
                        'MAX_WIDTH' => $arParams['LIST_MAX_WIDTH'],
                        'MAX_HEIGHT' => $arParams['LIST_MAX_HEIGHT'],
                    ),
                    $component
                );
                $APPLICATION->ShowViewContent('rs_catalog_sorter_template');
            ?></div><?
        }
        ?></td><?
    ?></tr><?
?></table>
```

Comment: Где сортировалось - в списке товаров? в топах товаров? в результатах поиска? Компоненты какие юзаются - свои или из коробки?

Comment: исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сортировка идёт в глобальных переменных *alfaCSortType* и *alfaCSortToo*

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    'bitrix:catalog.section',
    $alfaCTemplate,
    array(
    'IBLOCK_TYPE' => $arParams['IBLOCK_TYPE'],
    'IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'],
    'ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD' => $alfaCSortType, 
    'ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER' =>  $alfaCSortToo, 
    ...
```

А устанавливаются они судя по всему в этом компоненте:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    'redsign:catalog.sorter',
```

Answer (score 1):

Тема старая, но , думаю, актуальность не потеряла. Чтобы не писать сортировку каждый раз вручную, сделал бесплатное решение для вывода панели сортировки по стандартным полям таким как активность, популярность, название, , вес сортировки итд, по свойствам инфоблока, а так же по цене.
Можете установить через маркетплейс:

https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/codeblogpro.sortpanel/?sphrase_id=54141815#tab-rating-link

А можно взять компонент панели сортировки из git репозитория.
https://github.com/PanovAlexey/sort.panel

В описании модуля на маркетплейсе есть видео с примером установки модуля и добавлением компонента sort.panel на страницу сайта.

P.S.> решение так же предоставляет возможность сохранять выбранные параметры сортировки в сессии , чтобы выбранная сортировка сохранялась при переходе от раздела к разделу ( но это функция опциональная. Её можно выключить в настройках компонента).

С уважением.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно кому-то пригодиться. Настройка ранжирования в каталоге по цене делается в настройках компонента catalog в режиме правки.
Включаем на сайте режим правки, далее переходим в компоненты и выбираем каталог. Далее листаем до Настройки списка.
Тут выбираем как на изображении
[image: По какому полю сортируем товары в разделе]